# Custom web app home screen icon not showing on Samsung S4 Android 4.3

Tags: android, html, mobile, samsung-mobile

We have a web app that has a home screen icon defined like this:
`<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="http://example.com/icon.png">`

This has worked pretty much on all iOS and Android devices so far.

Though, now we have a case of a Samsung S4 Android 4.3 user where the generic bookmark icon on the home screen is shown instead of our custom app icon.

I've found one post in an Android forum that describes the same issue:
http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s4/342894-galaxy-s4-android-ver-4-3-has-bug-creating-webpage-shortcut.html
No solution was posted to that one.

We also tested with these two sites:
http://www.kylejlarson.com/blog/2013/adding-an-icon-for-iphone-ipad-android-to-your-website/
http://acegiak.net/

The second one uses the `rel="shortcut icon"` link additionally to the `rel="apple-touch-icon"` link, but the custom icon is still not shown (only the generic bookmark icon).

Anybody experienced the same and/or has an idea for a solution/workaround?
Thanks!

Note, that we're adding the app to the home screen by adding it to the bookmarks first, and then adding it to the home screen. We had issues on other devices where adding it directly to the home screen didn't show the icon either.

Answer (score 2):

The galaxy s4 has the option to open websites with 'internet' or 'googles Chrome'...when you safe bookmarks to the homescreen from 'internet', they will appear as generic icons...when you open the websites with 'Chrome' and add it to the homescreen - it will show the custom icon (apple-touch-icon).

Answer (score -1):

Try renaming your icon to /apple-touch-icon.png and then it should work!